# Copy many-to-many entries for new element

Tags: django, django-models

Django beginner here. I want to create a new row in a table and copy the references many-to-many entries from another row.

I have the following models (simplified):

```
class Missions(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Players, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    units = models.ManyToManyField(
        Units,
        through='MissionUnits'
    )

class MissionUnits(models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Missions, models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Units, models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['unit', 'mission'], name='unique_mission_units')
        ]
```

as well as two tables where unit player are defined.

So what I want to do is the following:

- I have an existing "Missions" entry with associated "MissionUnits" entries.
- I want to create a new "Missions" entry with the same "MissionUnits" as the old one
- The new entries should persist even if I delete the old "Missions" entry

Of course I could select all the "MissionUnits" entries, and extract and copy the information in a for loop, but is there also a more direct and elegant way to do this? If I just assign the oldmission.units to newmission.units, will this copy the elements?